# Lower bound for matrix vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

Let $\bf{A}$ be a semi-positive matrix, $\bf{I}$ is the identity matrix, and $\alpha \geq 0$. Let $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{y}$ be two vectors. I'm looking for a lower bound for the following quantity:

$${\bf Q} = ({\bf A} + \alpha {\bf I}) ({\bf x}-{\bf y}).$$

Can I say that the following holds true:
$$\| {\bf Q}  \| \geq \alpha \|{\bf x}-{\bf y} \|$$

EDIT: I managed to write the following as an attempt to prove the inequality.

Since ${\bf A} + \alpha \mathbf{I}$ a positive definite matrix, then its eigenvalue decomposition is given by
\begin{align}
{\bf A} + \alpha \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{P} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{P^T},    
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{P}$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues $\{\sigma_j\}_{j=1}^{d}$ on the diagonal. Note that $\mathbf{A}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, then $\sigma_j \geq \alpha, ~\forall j \in [d]$. Let $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{y}_1 - \mathbf{y}_2$, then we can write
\begin{align}\label{f0}
    \nonumber &\|\mathbf{Q}\|\\
    \nonumber &=\|\mathbf{P} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{P^T} \mathbf{y}\|\\
    &=\|\mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{P^T} \mathbf{y}\|,
\end{align}
where we have used the fact that for an orthogonal matrix, we have $\|\mathbf{P} \mathbf{x}\| = \|\mathbf{x}\|$. Let $\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{P^T} \mathbf{y}$, then we can write
\begin{align}
    \nonumber &\|\mathbf{Q}  \|\\
    \nonumber &=\|\mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{z}\|\\
    \nonumber &= \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^d \sigma_j^2 z_j^2}\\
&\geq \alpha \|\mathbf{z}\| = \alpha \|\mathbf{P^T} \mathbf{y}\| = \alpha \|\mathbf{y}_1-\mathbf{y}_2\|
\end{align}

Does this make sense?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You're more likely to receive an answer if you show effort to solve the problem on your own. What have you tried so far ???? Please **EDIT** your post to show us your work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried editing the post.

Comment: Note that if you don't have any additional constraints on $x,y$ then you can simply write $Q = (A+ \alpha I)z$ for some vector $z$.

Then at least
$$\frac{\vert \vert (A+\alpha I) z \vert \vert^2}{\vert \vert z \vert \vert^2} \geq \alpha $$ 
is a consequence of all eigenvalues of $A+\alpha I$ being of the form $\alpha + c$, where $c$ is a non-negative number.

Comment: @a_student: so in this case, I should have $\sqrt{\alpha}$ in the inequality I want to prove, right?